# How can a file be dropped into a Wine window?

Tags: wine, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to open a file in the program [GXSCC](http://www.geocities.co.jp/SiliconValley-SanJose/8700/P/GsorigE.htm). This program is designed to open files that are dropped into its window. How can I do this with the program running in Wine on Ubuntu? When I try to drop the file in, the file just pops back to its original location and the program doesn't open it. I'm using Wine 1.6.2.

[image]

Comment: Try upgrade wine — [in 1.7.20](https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTcxOTY) were drag'n'drop fixes, and overall wine-1.6.2 is really ancient.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this, you can always type the filename as a command line argument instead like `wine program file.midi`

Comment: @Hi-Angel Thanks for your suggestion. I've just tried this with Wine 1.9.13 and I'm still seeing the same problem.

Comment: @yentup Thanks for your suggestion. When I try this with some standard MIDI file, the program displays the message "Unknown files. can't playing.". Would you have any suggestions about how to get the program to access the MIDI file?

Comment: @d3pd as it still doesn't work, I'd suggest [to report a bug](https://wiki.winehq.org/Bugs).

Comment: @d3pd Is the midi file in the same directory as the .exe? It worked for me. Also, if the filename has spaces maybe replace them with underscores